# Prevent QLabel from resizing parent Widget

Tags: qt, pyqt, resize, pyside, qlabel

I have a `QLabel` inside a `QFrame`.

Sometimes I have too much text in the `QLabel` and it resizes the `QFrame` where it is in.

Now, I want to prevent the `QLabel` from resizing the `QFrame` where it resides in.
I don't want to limit the amount of lines or setting the maximum size of the `QLabel` because if the window size of the app increases, I do want to allow the `QLabel` to increase in size.

Just want to prevent the `QLabel` from expanding it's parent.

Any clean way to do it?

Comment: Don't put too much text in it? How do you want to handle the text that is not shown? `QLabel` is not designed to do it, you'll need a custom widget for that.

Comment: Just truncate the QLabel. show as much text as fits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `QScrollArea` (which inherits `QFrame`), and hide its scrollbars:

```
label = QtGui.QLabel(text)
frame = QtGui.QScrollArea()
frame.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
frame.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
frame.setWidgetResizable(True)
frame.setWidget(label)
```

This has the side-benefit that the user will still be able to view any hidden text by scrolling with the mouse-wheel.